# Book about a boy whose loved ones are possessed by a demon

Tags: story-identification, novel

About 8 years ago I read a book whose protagonist was an only child to a very poor but loving family. I think the setting was semi-modern, as the boy went to school and had school supplies like notebooks, but there was also a "kingdom and monarchs and servants" type section near the end. I read this book in Hebrew but it was definitely translated, probably from English.

In the beginning of the story the protagonist's mother was pregnant and had gotten very sick, so she and his father left to see a doctor away from town, leaving him alone for a few days. They come back with a healthy baby girl, and for a while everything is alright.

As his sister starts growing, the boy notices her staring at him whenever they are left alone, crying when he gets near her and hurting his arms by grabbing them tightly. When he tells his parents about this they say that he just misses being an only child, and decide that they have been coddling him too much. They start keeping him away from their bed at night, purposefully ignoring him, and only giving him short amounts of time to eat.

The boy sees something is wrong and runs away when he gets a bit older. He spends some time living in different places, leaving once the people he gets close to start acting like his family. One of these places was a big house with no door handles on the inside, where the children of a big family lived without adults. He spends a long time (years?) there, even falling in love with the big sister, until one night she looks at him with the same smile his sister had and he realizes she has been "possessed" this whole time.

He once again runs away, very depressed, and this is where the details start getting fuzzy in my head. He finds a girl living in a small shack, and that night she temporarily transforms into a demon. They figure out he is the only one who can see her, and that he is some kind of a lost prince of the kingdom.

At this point (or at some other point) there is an exposition about the war between heaven and hell, and about how good actions of humans create angels and bad actions create demons. The demons have been sending evil vibes to the human worlds to make more people do bad things, and the protagonist's demon is a part of that.

In the end, the good guys somehow win and banish the demons, and the protagonist (who is now a young adult) gets married to the demon girl. At their wedding his is reunited with his parents who apologize for everything, and he "meets" his sister for real for the first time.

As they are about to get married, an angel reveals that the protagonist is also an angel on a deep undercover mission from heaven, and that he must come back and be un-memory-wiped. He instead chooses to stay human, and in the final scene he is a poor painter living with his wife and their child. He tells them that they learned about the royal family in school and the parents look at each other and smile.

Some random scenes that stuck in my mind:

- Some time before his sister is born the protagonist is bullied by 2 bigger kids who tear apart his notebook, who also brag about their new job. He somehow gets the feeling that their new job is bullying him.
- 2 of the younger brothers in the house with no door handles would play a game after dinner, where the first one to ask the other one for anything would lose, giving up his dessert.
- The first night the girl transforms into a demon, the protagonist tries desperately to open the wooden door in the dark, and gets blood all over it. In the next morning, the girl is mad at him for damaging her door.
- At some point the boy remembers legends that he heard about some kind of demon, which might be implied to be the one he encounters, but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Any recollection what the cover art of the book was?  What format was it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really remember anything about its physical appearance. Couldn't tell you if it was paperback or hardback

Comment: Was it a Jewish book? There are Orthodox Jewish fantasy like this.

Comment: @TheAsh I can't say for sure since I was so young, but I don't remember it having those kinds of tones. Although I think the characters in the story did talk about demons of some kind, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: @Ynir this possibly? https://www.amazon.com/Warriors-Transcendence-Erez-Moshe-Doren/dp/9659134207?tag=namespacebran369-20

Comment: @Ynir https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA

Comment: @TheAsh No, that's not it. Also, the book was mostly focused on the main character and didn't have very intricate plotlines with many characters.